Failed to apply custom theme in Angular 18, some elements preserve original theme colors
Failed to apply custom theme, some elements preserve original theme colors.
Started a project with Cyan&Orange built-in theme and after that generated custom theme following the guide https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#custom-theme
ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme
? What HEX color should be used to generate the M3 theme? It will represent your primary color palette. (ex. #ffffff) #625690
? What HEX color should be used represent the secondary color palette? (Leave blank to use generated colors from Material) #615b71
? What HEX color should be used represent the tertiary color palette? (Leave blank to use generated colors from Material) #7d5262
? What HEX color should be used represent the neutral color palette? (Leave blank to use generated colors from Material) #111936
? What is the directory you want to place the generated theme file in? (Enter the relative path such as 'src/app/styles/' or leave blank to generate at your project root)
? Do you want to use system-level variables in the theme? System-level variables make dynamic theming easier through CSS custom properties, but increase the bundle size. Yes
? Choose light, dark, or both to generate the corresponding themes dark
CREATE m3-theme.scss (2765 bytes)

Applied newly created custom theme in styles.scss like so:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use './m3-theme';

@include mat.core();

:root {
  --mat-sidenav-container-width: 72px;
}


html {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  @include mat.core-theme(m3-theme.$dark-theme);
  @include mat.button-theme(m3-theme.$dark-theme);
  @include mat.all-component-themes(m3-theme.$dark-theme);

}

And some elements preserve orange color:

      <button
        type="button"
        mat-mini-fab
        (click)="drawerToggle(drawer)"
      >
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

Do I need to do something else?
Edit: I've created the stackblitz with this problem, mat-mini-fab button ignores custom palette. There are some differences from the above description to minimize codebase https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-puecui?file=src%2Findex.html

can you create a stackblitz?

Here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-puecui?file=src%2Findex.html
